# Transforming between two inertial frames

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames

Suppose I have two inertial frames, $ S $ and $ S' $. In the first frame, let $ a = \frac{\text{d}^2 x }{\text{d} t^2} $ and in the second, suppose
$$ a' = a \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  + v^2 \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2} + 2v \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial t } + \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial t^2} $$

(where $ x' = f(x(t),t) $ is the trajectory of the particle in $ S' $, $x=x(t)$ being the trajectory of the particle in $S$). Why must $ v^2 \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2} + 2v \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial t } + \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial t^2} = 0 $ ?

I get that the frames themselves are not accelerating but I can't seem to justify why this should be, rigorously. Also, I can't think of a (general) function $f$ that would satisfy these properties? Maybe if I could find it, it would show a result I could interpret...

Comment: In which view of physics? In Newtonian mechanics and in special relativity, acceleration is exactly the same in **all** inertial frames. This is not the case in general relativity. You need to add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: Sorry, it is Newtonian mechanics

Comment: In that case, this is a possible duplicate of [Inertial frames](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132677/inertial-frames), [Why can't we find a true inertial frame?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199791/why-cant-we-find-a-true-inertial-frame), and many, many more.

Comment: Where is $ x' = f(x(t),t) $ to be found? I can't see it. I can see $f$ though.

Comment: Just a note that this is the first problem in the following set: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/relativity/htl1.pdf

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, you are dealing with one spatial dimension and you are assuming that changing reference frame, the transformation of coordinates read
$$t'=t+c\:,\quad x' = f(x,t)\:.$$
The former just says that both reference frames are adopting  the **absolute time** of classical physics. The latter regards the Cartesian spatial coordinate of a given event which, in the non-primed reference frame, has coordinates $(x,t)$
Hence the coordinates of that event are $(x',t')$ in the other reference frame. I henceforth assume $c=0$ so that $t'=t$ and I will restore that constant at the end of computations. Taking the derivative with respect to $t$ or $t'$ produces the same result and for that reason the constant can be ignored.

Next, you consider the motion of a material point $x=x(t)$ and you want to describe the motion of the same point in the other reference frame:
$$x'(t) = f(x(t),t)\:.$$
Eventually, you want to determine the general function $f$ *by assuming that both reference frames are inertial*, according with the properties of $x(t)$ and $x'(t)$ for a *suitable family of motions*.

Well, let us consider the motion law of **isolated** material points, *also assuming to have at our disposal such a point in every chosen event and that we are free to fix its initial velocity with respect to a given referece frame* (the non-primed one).

Since both reference frames are inertial, the motion of such points has constant velocity, i.e. $a(t)=0$ and $a'(t)=0$ simultaneously.

Hence, from
$$a'(t) = a(t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{(x(t),t)}  + v(t)^2 \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}|_{(x(t),t)} + 2v(t) \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial t }|_{(x(t),t)} + \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial t^2}|_{(x(t),t)}$$
we find
$$0 =  v(t)^2 \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}|_{(x(t),t)} + 2v(t) \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial t }|_{(x(t),t)} + \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial t^2}|_{(x(t),t)}\:.$$
Let us focus attention on what happens at the initial instant $t=0$ (which however can be  fixed arbitrarily) where we can freely choose the initial velocity $v(0)$ and the initial position $x(0)$ of our material point in the non-primed inertial reference frame:
$$0 =  v(0)^2 \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}|_{(x(0),0)} + 2v(0) \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial t }|_{(x(0),0)} + \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial t^2}|_{(x(0),0)}\:.$$
By choosing $v(0)=0$, we find that
$$\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial t^2}|_{(x(0),0)}=0\:,$$
so that the initial  identity specialises to
$$0 =  v(0)^2 \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}|_{(x(0),0)} + 2v(0) \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial t }|_{(x(0),0)}\:.$$
Here, for instance choosing first $v(0)=1$ and next $v(0)=-1$, we immediately see that the further pair of requirements have to hold:
$$ \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}|_{(x(0),0)}= 0 \:, \quad \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial t }|_{(x(0),0)}=0\:.$$
Since the position $x(0)$ is arbitray and also the  initial time $t=0$ is arbitrary (we can change it simply by translating the origin of our time), we have actually found that
$$\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial t^2}|_{(x,t)}=0\:,  \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2}|_{(x,t)}= 0 \:, \quad \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial t }|_{(x,t)}=0\:.$$
In summary, the function $f$ must be a *linear, generally non-homogeneous map*:
$$x'= Ax + Bt+ C\:.$$
Restroring the constant $c$, we have found that, *if both reference frames are inertial*, then the transformation law of the coordinates of events are
$$t'=t+c\:, \quad x'= Ax + vt + d$$
The constant $A$ can be finally fixed to be $1$ by assuming that *distances of points at fixed time are independent from the reference frame* (absolute space in addition to absolute time of classical physics). The stadard Galileo's transformations show up this way:
$$t'=t+c\:, \quad x'= x + vt + d\:.\tag{1}$$

The result proves that the relativie motion of inertial frames is non-accelerated. Conversely if $S$ is inertial and $S'$ is not accelerated with respect to $S$, the acceleration of an isolated body is $0$ also in $S'$ in view of Galileo's law, hence also $S'$ is inertial.

Summing up, when assuming that time and space are absolute, if $S$ is inertial, then $S'$ is inertial *if and only if* $S'$ has motion with constant velocity with respect to $S$, that is equivalent to saying that  (1) is true.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly by an $f$ that satisfies these properties? The first equation is just what you get by differentiating $f(x(t),(t))$ twice, and the second is satisfied so long as $a'=a\frac{{\partial}f}{{\partial}x}$

But the question seems convoluted if you are talking about Newtonian reference frames - isn't it the case then that the only possible $f$ is $x+ut$ and so all your equations are trivially true?

Or is $x$ a variable that can be something other than a cartesian coordinate, in which case it would be possible that $a\not=a'$ and I would have to think more?
Edit: it's not always true for a general variable, only for a cartesian coordinate, that is one for which the definition of an inertial frame is $a=a'$

Answer (score 0):

If both frames are inertial, then neither is rotating.  The position and velocity of the of the origin of frame S' relative to the origin of frame S  can be specified by vectors R and V.  Then the position of an object can be specified by position vectors r = R + r'  and the velocity by vectors v = V + v'.  If you want to let one frame accelerate (but not rotate) then a = A + a'.  This assumes non-relativistic speeds.